# Why does attempt in calculating a histogram and back projection not work?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am attempting to calculate a histogram of a ROI in order to find that ROI in an image using back projection. My code is

```
        cvtColor(frame, hsvFrame, CV_BGR2HSV);

        cvtColor(ROI, hsvROI, CV_BGR2HSV);


        float hRanges[] = {0, 180};
        float sRanges[] = {0, 256};
        float vRanges[] = {0, 256};
        const float* ranges[] = { hRanges, sRanges, vRanges};

        int histSize = 256;
        int channels[] = {0,1,2};

        calcHist(&hsvROI, 1, channels, Mat(), ROIhist, 3, &histSize, ranges);
        calcBackProject(&hsvFrame, 1, channels, ROIhist, backProj, ranges, true);
        imshow("display", backProj);
```

Firstly, please assume all Mats have already been declared (this is only a snippet). In my understanding, the more dimensions/channels I use the more accurate the back projection should be...so i have decided to include all 3 channels of an HSV row, and therefore of course an HSV image (is this necessary? is there a better way?). In this example above, i get the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize, file opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 293
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:293: error: (-215) s >= 0 in function setSize
```

which gets triggered on the `CalcHist` line. My solution was to make sure `ROIhist` is of the same size as `hsvROI`, so I then put this line just before I declare the ranges:

```
Mat ROIhist(hsvROI.rows,hsvROI.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));
```

I think it worked, as on the next run, i got a different error that was triggered on the CalcBackProject line:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims > 0 && !hist.empty()) in calcBackProject, file /opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 1887
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:1887: error: (-215) dims > 0 && !hist.empty() in function calcBackProject
```

Which i really do not understand. In fact I also feel like my previous fix by adding the Mat constructor shouldn't be necessary anyway...?

I essentially need to be able to calculate this back projection as accurately as possible while using both functions in ideally a rather simple and standard way. My attempt clearly has some logic flaw somewhere and I would appreciate an explanation or suggestion to how i should go about this properly to get the best results. Thanks in advance !

Comment: We need a [MCVE] in order to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

`histSize` in your case should be the number of bins in your 3D histogram (so an int array, not just an int). And I'd use lower numbers for them, so that more pixels would manage to fall into one bin, and would make your backprojection more meaningful:

```
    int histSize[] = {32, 32, 32};
    ...
    calcHist(&hsvROI, 1, channels, Mat(), ROIhist, 3, histSize, ranges);
```